# Where can I find (free) "deep-dive" materials related to Taproot?

Tags: taproot

I'm not sure how much bitcoin stack exchange is really meant for questions like this (this is probably more for reddit) but maybe someone can help me. I'm totally fine if the question is closed.

Namely, I'm wondering if any of you have any material that can explain everything related to taproot in the smallest details ("deep dive to taproots")? Something similar to how the Bitcoin Master book explains all the other aspects of bitcoin, so some material that explains taproot in minute detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-exhaustive list but these are some of the best resources to get started:

- Bitcoin Optech [Preparing for Taproot](https://bitcoinops.org/en/preparing-for-taproot/) series
- Bitcoin Optech [Taproot workshop](https://github.com/bitcoinops/taproot-workshop)
- Bitcoin Optech [Taproot workshop videos](https://bitcoinops.org/en/schorr-taproot-workshop/)
- [BIP 340: Schnorr signatures](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki)
- [BIP 341: Taproot](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki)
- [BIP 342: Tapscript](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki)

There are a [number](https://btctranscripts.com/tags/taproot/) of presentations, transcripts out there for **more accessible** insights into Taproot than the BIPs including this [presentation](https://btctranscripts.com/sf-bitcoin-meetup/2018-07-09-taproot-schnorr-signatures-and-sighash-noinput-oh-my/) from Pieter Wuille at SF Bitcoin Devs in 2018 (thanks deyw) and this London BitDevs [Socratic Seminar](https://btctranscripts.com/london-bitcoin-devs/2020-07-21-socratic-seminar-bip-taproot/) with Pieter Wuille and Russell O'Connor in 2020.

The Q&As on this StackExchange site (tagged [taproot](/questions/tagged/taproot)) are also a great Taproot resource.

The [3rd edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-bitcoin-3rd/9781098150082/) of Mastering Bitcoin (Antonopoulos, Harding) will cover Taproot and is expected in December 2023.